# How to set and save metadata of mp3 file using mp3agic in Scala

Tags: scala, mp3, mp3agic

I'm trying to write my own mp3 player.  I am able to use mp3agic to read the metadata from an mp3 file, so now I'd like to modify it.  Mp3agic shows (under heading *Setting ID3v2 field values* at [mp3agic on GitHub](https://github.com/mpatric/mp3agic)) that you can do it by modifying the tag, then calling save on the mp3 file.

I get an error when I call save.  It's the same error as another post [Change Album names using mp3agic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44893480/change-album-names-using-mp3agic)

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mpatric.mp3agic.NotSupportedException: Packing Obselete frames is not supported
    at com.mpatric.mp3agic.ID3v2ObseleteFrame.packFrame(ID3v2ObseleteFrame.java:32)
    at com.mpatric.mp3agic.ID3v2Frame.toBytes(ID3v2Frame.java:83)
    at com.mpatric.mp3agic.AbstractID3v2Tag.packSpecifiedFrames(AbstractID3v2Tag.java:275)
    at com.mpatric.mp3agic.AbstractID3v2Tag.packFrames(AbstractID3v2Tag.java:261)
    at com.mpatric.mp3agic.AbstractID3v2Tag.packTag(AbstractID3v2Tag.java:227)
    at com.mpatric.mp3agic.AbstractID3v2Tag.toBytes(AbstractID3v2Tag.java:218)
    at com.mpatric.mp3agic.Mp3File.save(Mp3File.java:450)
    at Example$.$anonfun$new$2(Example.scala:16)
```

code

```
import java.nio.file.Paths
import com.mpatric.mp3agic.Mp3File

object Example extends App {
  Paths.get("content").resolve("raw").toFile.listFiles.toList
    .find(f => f.isFile && f.getName.endsWith(".mp3"))
    .foreach { file =>
      val mp3 = new Mp3File(file)
      println(mp3.hasId3v1Tag)
      println(mp3.hasId3v2Tag)
      println(mp3.hasCustomTag)

      val tag = mp3.getId3v2Tag
      println(tag.getYear)
      tag.setComment("Cool song.")
      mp3.save(file.getParentFile.toPath.resolve("x.mp3").toFile.getAbsolutePath)
    }
}
```

Output

```
false
true
false
1973
```

sbt

```
scalaVersion := "2.13.1"
libraryDependencies += "com.mpatric" % "mp3agic" % "0.9.1"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to set new metadata on an mp3 file, but I had to create a new tag and copy all the data from the old tag over to it, then save the file with the new tag.